# How do I make "X is the thing I wanted to win" unambiguous?

Tags: ambiguity, subjects

When I say, *StackExchange is the website I wanted to win* (in an implied context of best website award), it sounds like I wanted to win (own) StackExchange, whereas I'm trying to imply that I wanted StackExchange to win the best website award. Am I wrong?

Is the following statement: *StackExchange is the website I wanted to win the award* correct?

How do I communicate my wish for an entity to win, without sounding like I wanted to own them, in the same pattern, *[Subject] is the entity I wanted [verb??] win*, and without explicitly mentioning that it's the award that I want them to win.

I'm looking for a structuring of that sentiment that is unambiguous, rather than a solution which requires more context in or around the sentiment itself.

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker, and my knowledge is mostly ad-hoc,  which means that I might have made mistakes in naming parts of speech, and even categorizing this question. Could someone please be kind enough to recategorize?

Comment: I wanted StackExchange to win [ the award].

Comment: What is this award everyone is talking about? No one ever tells me anything!

Comment: @Jim Thanks. This is not the pattern I'm looking for. In this pattern, I don't even need to mention the context (award). I can simply say, `I wanted SE to win`. There is no confusion here. Ambiguity would be when I say, `SE is the website I wanted to win`. I could say `SE is the website I wanted to win the award` which would make it clearer, although I'm not sure if its even right. But what I'm looking for is a sentence according to the pattern, and without explicitly mentioning the context. I don't really need it, I'm just trying to understand if the point I'm making in my first EDIT is right

Comment: The point is, the way to fix ambiguity is to reword and the most direct rewording is the wording I provided.  Having said that, @LittleEva is right that given the proper context (We both know that an award is being given to a website) saying, "StackExchange is the website I wanted to win." there is little chance of being interpreted the wrong way.  Nobody thinks you are in a position to win a website, so nobody will think that's what you meant.

Comment: @Jim, while that may be the case, as I said, I'm not looking to actually use it, I'm looking to understand what is the right usage. And to me, it seems that `<Obj Clause> I wanted to win` seems like I wanted to win them.

Comment: Well, even if it seems that way, it won't be taken that way unless the context indicates it should be.  Most sentences are ambiguous if taken out of context.

Comment: @Jim Its likely that my lack of English knowledge is coming in way of my understanding, but I'll try- in this case, I'm not talking about ambiguity. I'm talking about whether its even correct to say `<Obj clause> I wanted to win` when meaning `I wanted <sbj clause> to win`. (Please pardon if I've made mistake in naming the parts of speech)

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine to say, "StackExchange is the website I wanted to win".  but you could also say, "StackExchange is the website I wanted to *see* win."

Comment: But you're doing good, user18151. Your writing here is very clear. What makes your construction ambiguous is te order of your sentence "**StackExchange is the website I wanted to win**" Jim & I would naturally avoid that construction BECAUSE it lends itself to ambiguity. Tell 18151 why, Jim. :-)

Comment: Please [edit] this to use full words rather than obscure abbreviations like "sb". And your sentence will be fine when it's used in context.

Comment: @Jim See win does seem like it would keep me happy for now :-). Thank you! Do you want to add that as an answer?

Comment: @LittleEva Thank you, I try to learn. English is not my first language, and I've lost grasp over some grammar off late...

Comment: Whoever downvoted, its proper manners to explain what's wrong with the question.

Comment: Don't worry about downvotes, 18151. We all get them. Just do your best. There is a saying, "use it, or lose it." Use your English skills or they will fade away, get "rusty". :-)

Comment: @LittleEva Thank you. You know it turns out there is an 'award' going on. http://english.stackexchange.com/stackegg/leaderboard . Look to the top of the right side-bar...

Comment: You might want to wait a bit longer before selecting a specific answer - otherwise you might put other posters off answering and giving you helpful insights - especially if they've already spent hours writing up part of an answer for you! ;)

Comment: @Araucaria: Thanks. I figured that you decided to not post an answer after Shoe's.
 I was going to put a 50 points bounty on this (and will), so please keep the answers coming! Thank you!
I selected the answer a while back, so cannot change now... :-)

Comment: @Araucaria: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252624/an-optional-reminder-to-select-an-answer-after-2-days-of-the-first-answer-upvote Let us see...

Comment: @Araucaria Due to some SO weirdness, Shoe's answer is no longer the answer. If you still submit yours I'll throw another bounty anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Out of context the sentence *StackExchange is the website I wanted to win* is inherently ambiguous because of the nature of the verb *to win*, which is [ambitransitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambitransitive_verb). In other words, *win* can be both transitive and intransitive:

> She won the award. (transitive)
>
> She won. (intransitive)

So if Polly is a cat and I read the decontextualised sentence *Polly is the cat she wanted to win*, I cannot know if she wanted to win Polly (transitive), eg. in a competition to win a cat. Or if Polly is a cat that she hoped would win in a *Best Cat* competition.

The ambiguity does not arise in similar constructions where the verb has only a transitive meaning:

> Polly is the cat I want to have.
>
> ELL is the site he likes to consult.
>
> Your daughter is the child you need to hug.

*Polly*, *StackExchange* and *your daughter* are objects of the transitive verbs to *have*, *consult* and *hug*; they cannot be the subjects of those verbs.

Nor does ambiguity arise with intransitive-only verbs in these (somewhat contrived) sentences:

> Mary is the girl I want to sit.
>
> StackExchange is the site I least want to die.

*Mary* and *StackExchange* are the subjects of *sit* and *die*. They cannot be the objects of these intransitive verbs.

I have not been able to think of a particularly plausible example of a sentence containing an ambitransitive verb that is likely to be ambiguous in the way that *Polly is the cat she wanted to win* is. Possibly:

> The sax is the instrument she wanted to play

which could be construed as *She wanted to play the sax* (transitive) or *She wanted to hear the sax play* (intransitive) - as the next instrument in an improvised jazz piece.

As several of the comments above indicate, the context is almost always sufficient to disambiguate meaning. But in this case, adding the verb *to see*, as suggested, makes the meaning absolutely clear:

> StackExchange is the website I wanted to see win

Comment: Great explanation, thank you! This also means, that my arguments against @LittleEva and Jim were wrong- its possible to use intransitive verbs in this context. "SE is what I didn't want to die". Brilliant, thanks again! On that note, would the following sentence be okay: SE is the website he wished would win?

Comment: Yes, _SE is the website he wished would win_ means he wanted SE to win. And if it were possible to win a website and the one he wanted to win was SE, then you would need to insert a second he: _SE is the website he wished he would win._

Comment: I request that last quote to be at the top. TL;DR, add the word *see*.

Comment: Notice this also implies you could simply change "win" to some other intransitive verb which is not ambitransitive to remove the ambiguity.  For example, you could use **triumph**, as in _StackExchange is the website I wanted to triumph._

Comment: This is baffling, I marked your answer as correct, and couldn't unmark it when @Araucaria wanted it so. In any case I wanted to award the bounty to you, but for some reason your answer is was no longer the answer. Sorry for the confusion. Would start another bounty soon.

Comment: @user18151. Don't worry about it. It's enough for me if you found my answer helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Although there is technically ambiguity in your original phrase, the context makes it very obvious which meaning you meant. However, if you are really desperate for a phrase with no ambiguity I would go for:

> I wanted Stack Exchange to win

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer. I'm aware of restructuring to make it better, but I wanted to know if the pattern that I mentioned can be used as such.

Comment: @user18151 - What? Your original question says *"I'm looking for a structuring of that sentiment that is unambiguous"*. That is what I have provided you!

Comment: Third paragraph: "In the same pattern" ! :-)
Or first paragaraph, second last statement :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you could structure this sentence, all of which would convey your point precisely as you mean it. Firstly, you could say "I hope that StackExchange wins [the Best Website Award]". This implies that, of the various potential 'nominees' for the Best Website Award, you want StackExchange to win the award. Alternatively, you could say "In my opinion, StackExchange should win [the Best Website Award]." This implies the exact same thing as the previous example, but makes the statement seem more opinion based. I have included the Best Website Award in brackets so that if you do need to be more explicit in your statement, you can use the term.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer. I'm aware of restructuring to make it better, but I wanted to know if the pattern that I mentioned can be used as such.

Comment: It's alright as it is, because most people will understand what you mean, without interpreting it as though StackExchange was a carnival prize.

Answer (score 1):

The second way you phrased it in the question was clear:
**"I wanted StackExchange to win [the best website award.]"**
The bit in square brackets could be omitted if clear from context, to satisfy your requirement "without explicitly mentioning that it's the award that I want them to win."

Answer (score 1):

I believe a change in verb would help.

> StackExchange is the website I **hoped would** win.

Answer (score 0):

Less ambiguous:

***The website*** [that/which] I **wanted** to win the award **was StackExchange.**

***The website*** [that/which] I **want** to win the award **is StackExchange.**

Comment: I'm going to ask a stupid question (and to other answerers, please don't feel your efforts are in vain, I'm still trying to learn! :-)) - Is the above statement even grammatically correct? 
Or it is, and it is along the same line as- "Mary is the girl I want to sit" , and hence correct?

Comment: @user18151 Which statement exactly? They are all "above."

Comment: Either of the statements.

Comment: @user18151 Still confusing: those in the OP, those in my answer? QUOTE them.

Comment: Your question, "The website that  I want to win the award is SE"

Comment: @user18151 If I put it up, I consider it correct. Consult with others, if you wish, about it, I said my piece.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22527/discussion-between-marius-hancu-and-user18151).

Comment: This phenomenon is one of the sogenannte ["Teddy facts", as Pullum calls them](http://lingo.stanford.edu/sag/papers/pullum97.pdf), referring to George Lakoff's 1970 paper on Global Rules that used the example sentence _Teddy is the man I want to succeed,_ among other variants. It's part of a much bigger complexity, which Pullum's article goes into quite deeply.

Comment: @John Lawler Thank you, Professor Lawler. I'll try to see what I can understand from the reference that you generously shared with us.

Comment: Good luck. Bear in mind that, to linguists, the **pronunciation** is the language. It's what people do naturally. Written language doesn't capture most of that, and therefore has far more ambiguity than real (i.e, spoken) language. The paper is about the correct analysis of words like _wanna, gonna, gotta, hafta, shoulda, wouldna,_ etc. Correct, at least, to Pullum, who has his own analyses to present. But the fact is that in speech these two senses of the written sentence are easily distinguished, and there is no ambiguity.